# Whitespace increases after hiding several elements rdlc report

Tags: rdlc, removing-whitespace

I have several Tablixes in my RDLC report that each one display/hide based on its own data existence condition. sometimes when 3 or 4 several tablixes set to hidden, an empty space increases between displaying items based on number of hidden tables. How can I keep this space constant ignoring number of hidden elements?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of separating tables with white spaces you can add an extra row header with no border that will be hide with its table.

For example:

- TABLE 1: no extra row header
- TABLE 2: yellow row header
- TABLE 3: orange row header
- TABLE 4: red row header

[image: example]

Comment: some questions:
1. how to make all tables contiguous without white space then? rdlc doesn't truly support item overlapping.
2. How to keep this row height the same for all tables? I can't set height in the row properties.

Comment: 1. you have to manually setting `.Location` according to previous table `.Location` and `.Height` properties; 2. setting `.Height` property of a single cell